# Converting a Plane to FiniteSet in SymPy

Tags: python, geometry, sympy

I am currently working with 3D geometry and I decided to use `sympy.geometry` to manage objects in space.

I had to solve a non-linear system of equations to find the intersection between a plane and a sphere, which yields a `FiniteSet` as a result (which is the correct equation of  the circle, so that works). After that, I have to find the intersection between this circle and another plane, which I'm finding difficult to do as the two objects are of different type, so no direct comparison can be done.

I am asking if there is any automatic way of converting a `Plane` object from the module into a `FiniteSet` or I have to do it manually by defining a symbolic set with the coordinates of the points on the plane (which can be done as I have full description of this new plane).

**Edit**: By equation of the circle, I mean the following. The set is described as a collection of points (in the example, the circle is perpendicular to the z=0 plane, but this has to be done in general so few assumptions can be made to simplify the problem):

```py
FiniteSet((70,18-sqrt(-(z-6)(z-2)),z),(70,18+sqrt(-(z-6)(z-2)),z))
```

Here, z is bound to be real so it is limited to the [2,4] interval.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking for here. The intersection between a plane and a sphere will be a circle but that is an *infinite* set of points.

Comment: Well yes, but somehow it is represented by a ```FiniteSet``` in ```sympy```. A plane is also an infinite set of points, but I guess there should be a way of representing it as a ```FiniteSet``` aswell.